# Vue Component Issue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have this page I want to try out Vue Router with Vue Components. I cant figure out whats wrong. I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` at this line `const App = new Vue.extend({})`

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>

    <template id="foo"> <h1>This is homepage</h1> </template>

    <template id="bar"> <h1>This is Bar page</h1> </template>


</body>

    //Vue.js v1.0.28
<script src="{{ asset( 'js/vue.js' ) }}"></script>

// vue-router v0.7.13
    <script src="{{ asset( 'js/vue-router.js' ) }}"></script>

    <script>

            const router = new VueRouter()

            const App = new Vue.extend({})

            router.map({
              '/': {
                component: {
                        template: '#foo'
                    }
              },
              '/bar': {
                component: {
                    template: '#bar'
                }
              },
            })

            router.start(App, '#app')

    </script>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Okay, I have managed to get this working.

```
const Foo = Vue.component('foo', {  template: '#foo' });
const Bar = Vue.component('bar', {  template: '#bar' });

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter()

router.map({
  '/foo': {
    component: Foo
  },
  '/bar': {
    component: Bar
  },
})

var App = Vue.extend({})

router.start(App, 'body')
```

What I need now is to extract those templates from index.blade.php into their own files like `Foo.vue` and `Bar.vue`. How do I do that?

I am using Webpack to compile assets.

Comment: If you want to create some `.vue` files, just take the content from `#foo` and `#bar` and insert them into the relevant sections according to the `.vue` file  spec: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/start/spec.html

Comment: I have tried it and used `const Bar = Vue.component('bar', require('./Bar.vue'););` and then `router.map({ '/bar': {  component: Foo  } })` gives me a blank page

Comment: `/bar` is trying to load the component `Foo`? Shouldn't it be `component: Bar`?

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use vue-router v.v2.2.1 and you can check this official example https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0 and here router code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

import { createListView } from '../views/CreateListView'
import ItemView from '../views/ItemView.vue'
import UserView from '../views/UserView.vue'

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  scrollBehavior: () => ({ y: 0 }),
  routes: [
    { path: '/top/:page(\\d+)?', component: createListView('top') },
    { path: '/new/:page(\\d+)?', component: createListView('new') },
    { path: '/show/:page(\\d+)?', component: createListView('show') },
    { path: '/ask/:page(\\d+)?', component: createListView('ask') },
    { path: '/job/:page(\\d+)?', component: createListView('job') },
    { path: '/item/:id(\\d+)', component: ItemView },
    { path: '/user/:id', component: UserView },
    { path: '/', redirect: '/top' }
  ]
})
```